# Returning iMac to iSpot when bought from online shop

Tags: mac, exchange

I bought an iMac from the online Apple Store and now, 2 days after purchase, it broke down. I want to return it/exchange it, but would like to avoid the tremendous waiting time, as this used to be my working tool (I work at home) and make the exchange at an iSpot, is this possible or must I bear that waiting time?

Comment: I feel your pain. Are there any Apple retail stores located somewhat close to you?

Comment: close to me, only ispot

Comment: actually that ispot happens to be a service point

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get any Mac repaired (including warranty repair) at any Apple Store or Apple Authorized repair shop, regardless of where you purchased the machine.

If you're actually looking to *return* the Mac, you should call Apple Customer Support to see if you can return it at the store.